# On click event of a keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When you click on a textfield in your iphone application, you will get the keyboard displayed. On that keyboard you will get a `GO`, `DONE` and `SEARCH` buttons. I need to get the On click event of these buttons.

What are they ?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about a return event, i.e. when the user clicks the done/blue button? Or any of the keys i.e. letters?

Comment: No, only the return button, where it says DONE, SEARCH, RETURN, GO

Answer (score 4):

become the delegate of the text field in question and you get sent

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

When the user taps the return button, whatever the label on the button is. (GO, SEARCH or DONE)